# Magento 2.1.6 - Backslash before PATH - Error

Tags: magento2, catalog, magento2.1.5, frontend-error

After the update from **2.1.5** -> **2.1.6**, I can't reach the ***Catalog page*** anymore.

I see there is a `"/"` in front of my path.

This isn't working:

```
\C:/www/Project/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\13517afb0cee4c0f4b3aa2fcc6e8c947\/d/r/drew-pink.jpg
```

But this does:

```
C:/www/Project/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\13517afb0cee4c0f4b3aa2fcc6e8c947\/d/r/drew-pink.jpg
```

How do I get rid of this 'Backslash'?

Error:

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to write file into directory \C:/www/Project/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\13517afb0cee4c0f4b3aa2fcc6e8c947\/d/r/drew-pink.jpg. Access forbidden.

Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to write file into directory \C:/www/Project/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\13517afb0cee4c0f4b3aa2fcc6e8c947\/d/r/drew-pink.jpg. Access forbidden.
#0 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php(141): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->_prepareDestination('\\C:/www/Project...', 'drew-pink.jpg')
#1 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(79): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->save('\\C:/www/Project...', NULL)
#2 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Image.php(677): Magento\Framework\Image->save('\\C:/www/Project...')
#3 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php(465): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image->saveFile()
#4 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php(534): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->applyScheduledActions()
#5 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder.php(132): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getResizedImageInfo()
#6 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct.php(517): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder->create()
#7 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'category_page_g...', Array)
#8 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor.php(468): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getImage', Array, Array)
#9 C:\www\Project\app\design\frontend\Project\shop\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml(52): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'category_page_g...')
#10 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('C:\\www\\Project...')
#11 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor), 'C:/www/Project...', Array)
#12 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/www/Project...')
#13 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->fetchView('C:/www/Project...')
#14 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#15 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor.php(882): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#16 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->toHtml()
#17 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('category.produc...')
#18 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#19 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#20 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('category.produc...', true)
#21 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(499): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('category.produc...', true)
#22 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Category\View.php(98): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('product_list')
#23 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\category\products.phtml(18): Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View->getProductListHtml()
#24 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('C:\\www\\Project...')
#25 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View), 'C:/www/Project...', Array)
#26 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/www/Project...')
#27 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#28 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#29 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('category.produc...')
#30 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#31 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#32 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('category.produc...', true)
#33 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('category.produc...')
#34 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#35 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#36 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#37 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#38 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#39 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#40 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#41 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#42 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#43 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#44 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#45 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#46 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#47 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#48 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#49 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#50 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#51 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#52 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#53 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#54 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#55 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#56 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#57 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#58 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#59 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#60 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#61 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#62 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#63 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#64 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#65 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#66 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#67 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#69 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#70 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#71 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#73 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#74 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#75 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#76 C:\www\Project\var\generation\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#77 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#78 C:\www\Project\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#79 C:\www\Project\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#80 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related with the relative path. Check this link for the fix
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9212